# Dynamically modify form action based on dropdownlist value

Tags: model-view-controller, forms, dynamic, action

I have a partial view (search.ascx), which contains a dropdownlist, a text field and a submit button.

When clicking the submit button, I would like the forms action method to reflect the chosen value in the dropdownlist.

E.g. the drowpdownlist contains values such as:

- DVD
- Blueray
- VHS

So, by selecting "VHS", the final action url should be:

site.com/DVD?search=TextDefinedInTheTextField. 
How to do this?

**Current implementation**

```
 <% using(Html.For.BeginForm("List", "Products", FormMethod.Get)) { %>
    <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryName, Model.TopLevelCategoriesList, new {@class = "searchCategoryDropDown" })%>
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SearchString, new {@class = "searchField" })%>
    <a>
        <input class="searchBtn" id="searchButton" type="submit" value="Søg" />
    </a>
<% } %>
```

The issue with the above implementation is, that the generated "form" tag created is static, and does not reflect the dropdownlist value.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE SOLUTION**
So, i figured it out, by using Jquery you can modify the action on the form dynamically.

```
$(function () {
    $('#searchForm').submit(function () {
    this.action = $('#searchCategory').val();
   return true;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of fiddling with dynamic action on the client side which could have its own host of issues if javascript fails, disabled, etc - why not just simply handle this action in the controller?
Its a bit more readable. Since your view is being rendered by I'm assuming a single controller with all of these options, consider a single controller method to handle the post and determine what to do. Its a bit more readable that way too.

Comment: You are right, I have actually considered this. But, I havn't found any right solution, as I would have nice and clear urls like: domain.com/DVD?search=TheMatrix. If I should do as you recommend, which I also believe is the right solution, then my urls would be: domain.com/?category=DVD&search=TheMatrix. Am I right, or is there a nice way of avoiding that?

Comment: If you are posting your form then there is your base URL and your controllers method signature can bind a parameter to the name from the combobox or your Model or even just read it from the form directly in your controllers method. Just make sure your forms method value is post not get.